Why does Clang forbid qualifiers on anonymous bit fields?
I have the following test code:
struct{
      const int   : 1;
      const int b : 1;
} bit = {0};

int main(void) {
    return bit.b;
}

Most compilers, including latest GCC, compile it just fine, but Clang, starting with version 8, complains about "const" on an anonymous bit field:
[source]:2:22: error: anonymous bit-field cannot have qualifiers
     const int   : 1;

The same error happens with "volatile" qualifier. What is the reason Clang is so strict about qualifiers, and is there a way to silence this error?
Background: I have auto-generated "hardware register definition" header files which represent unused bits and anonymous bit fields, and qualifiers such as "volatile const" or "volatile" are systematically used on all bits in a register. Going through such files and manually removing qualifiers on anonymous fields is not an option.

The type of a bit-field can only be integral or (possibly cv-qualified) enumeration type, an unnamed bit-field cannot be declared with a cv-qualified type.. My guess they can be used only as padding bit, so qualifiers are meaningless. standard says "shall not". Does it leave room to compilers to do what they want?

would using a script to do the removal task be acceptable?

Also know that bitfields probably do NOT do what you think they do. The compiler is free to implement bitfields any way it wants (within the limits of your specified types). At best what it does is generate an integer variable that as 1 bit arithmetic not a variable that exaclty occupies one bit in your variable. So having an unnamed bit field in there would not serve any (logical) purpose.

What you probably should use is std::bitset<>  (no control over underlying type) or write a small class that does bitwise operations on an underlying type for you

@Oersted shall not in standard speak means it's not allowed or conforming compiler should reject this code. C++ standard follows ISO OBP for terminology (per intro.defs#2.1), and OBP says "shall not -
indicates requirements to be followed strictly to conform to the document and from which no deviation is permitted"

@Yksisarvinen Thanks. Thus, cl and gcc are wrong?

@Oersted For now, the acceptable solution is simply switch to GCC, however, I'm trying to anticipate the possibility of having to fix the software after a GCC upgrade. And yes, modifying with a script would be my fallback plan.

@PepijnKramer Those are very valid points, however, even today a lot of hardware description headers define device registers using bit fields, and rely on compilers to pack them together, including unnamed fields.

@DmitryGrigoryev Then you rely on that specific compiler to do the correct thing (have you verified the assembly is doing that?). I still would advise you to make a small class template that does the bit operations for you (possibly even add some constexpr stuff to move things to compile time which is good for embedded to).

You gave me a bit of inspiration to try this : https://godbolt.org/z/8WecqTaoM

@PepijnKramer For SW builds targeting actual hardware, I'm using the compiler that the ASIC manufacturer recommends, so verifying the assembly would be their responsibility. This is also why I want to avoid touching these manufacturer-provided headers: I don't want to be responsible for testing and maintenance. For test builds (e.g. unit tests with Google Test), I don't actually care how the compiler allocates bit fields.

@DmitryGrigoryev A fair approach in this case (vendor specific compiler + vendor specific hardware). I am just more used to write portable code and then "implementation defined" in the C++ standard is a bit of a tricky area.

Because Clang implements CWG2229 (which made it ill-formed to use a cv-qualified type for an unnamed bit-field), but GCC does not.
Clang currently has no option to ignore this error. This is not valid C++, you will have to re-autogenerate your structs (either without qualified types or with a name like _padding1).

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Adding a name makes it no longer an unnamed bit-field. I think Microsoft does this for all their bit-fields

d'oh. need more coffee

I think the reason why this was not done in the first place is auto-completion. On modern ASICs all registers are the same size (e.g. 32-bit), even if only a couple of bits is actually used. You don't want users to type Uart->CtlrReg. and see a popup filled with useless _paddingX names.
